# simple program that switches numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, numbers

Hello I'm trying to write a program that will receive a number from the user
if its an even number (for example 9728 the program will change it to 7982)

if its an odd number (for example 1234567 the program will change it to 1325476 ,the left number will stay the same)

for some reason only the second option is working. thanks for helping

```
int firstnumber, mull = 1, sum = 0, i = 0;
int rightDigit;
System.out.println("Please enter a number");

firstnumber = s.nextInt();

while (firstnumber != 0) {
    rightDigit=firstnumber%10;
    rightDigit*=mull;

    if((firstnumber > 9) && (i%2==0)){
        rightDigit*=10;
    }
    else if ((firstnumber > 9) && (i%2!=0)){
        rightDigit/=10;
    }

    sum+=rightDigit;
    mull*=10;
    firstnumber/=10;
    i++;
}
System.out.println("Your number is " + sum);
```

Comment: When you say "even number" and "odd number" do you mean that literally, or do you mean numbers with an even number of digits vs an odd number of digits?

Comment: Hi ben. i mean a number with even charecters( 1234,12,345678), and odd as (123,34566,3455678)

Comment: I assume this is for a class.  Have you learned about strings and characters yet?  I ask because this would be more easily solved with strings than with mathematical operations.

Comment: not yet. only allowed to use loops o_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is messing up on the last digit when you have an even number of digits. Try taking firstnumber > 9 out of the else clause:

```
else if (i%2!=0){
    rightDigit/=10;
}
```